# Ethereum node indexer

Tags: nodes, archive-node

I'm looking for some open source indexer for a geth node. I've found [this](https://github.com/Adamant-im/ETH-transactions-storage) but it only indexes erc20 txs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ethereum ETL](https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl) might work for you.

It indexes:

- Blocks
- Transactions
- Traces
- ERC20
- ERC721

There is also a [public BigQuery dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain) being fed by this ETL which you might use instead of indexing it all yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Subsquid](https://www.subsquid.io) (disclosure: I'm affiliated). Can do events, transactions, traces and state diffs. You can use it with a free data lake called Archive to save yourself some time, or index from scratch through an RPC endpoint.